# Google analytics doesn't track IE visitors?

Tags: google-analytics

My google analytics code doesn't seem to be tracking Internet Explorer visitors. See data below.

1. Chrome 1,000   57.01%
2. Firefox 638    36.37%
3. Safari 50  2.85%
4. Opera  42  2.39%
5. IE 13  0.74%

87% are Windows users, 10% Mac. These hits are during work hours. Out of the IE visitors the distribution is:

-IE10 `1`

-IE9 `14`

-IE8 `5`

-IE7 `1`

(got a few more hits since the original post, still @ 1% though)

With that number of visitors, it seems extremely unlikely that less than 1% are using IE.

I'm using the unaltered JS code provided by Google.

It's a Rails app running inside a Facebook page tab, and the users are probably a bit more tech savvy than average, but not overly so.

What could the issue be? Is it indeed extremely unlikely that so few users could be on IE? I'd assume that for even for the most computer-savvy crowds (which this is not) there'd still be a much higher percentage of IE users, especially during work hours.

## Edit

Found a clue. I have this code before the analytics code:

```
    /[if lt IE 9]
        = javascript_include_tag "//ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"
```

That triggers a JS error in IE (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null), but the rest of the JS still loads and functions fine on IE8 and 9. I've tested both versions and have had others confirm (frequently produces the error, but the rest of the JS always works). Why would a JS error prevent the GA code from loading?

Comment: You have some reputation and badges - you MUST know this isn't enough information. Where is your code? What have you tried? What's your IE version breakout? Are those 13 all from a specific version? What else have you segmented that traffic by?

Comment: Maybe your app doesn't render right in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this, but you can test the validity by creating a new page that only you know how to get to. And then tracking your IE visits.